# Custom Freeze Button on User Detail

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

To start, I have already read Bob Buzzard's article, http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2013/11/freezing-users-from-visualforce.html, and incorporated a lot of what he's used. At this point, I am now trying to create a button on a specific user detail that I could click to freeze/unfreeze a user (as if the user was a System Administrator, but isn't) We want to give selected access to this capability to certain users. Because then after the special user freezes another user, we want them to click a custom button also on the user detail page to pull up a report to see what sales desk they are on, so that we can reassign those responsibilities before we deactivate the user completely. What I currently have involves pulling up a visualforce page to select the user. The difficulty is that we have to work with the UserLogin object, which isn't accessible through apex. I've attached the code I have at the moment, which works, but is a visualforce page instead of being accessed directly from the User detail page. Thanks in advance!

**Update**
Looks like you can't create custom buttons for the User object per https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_considerations.htm&language=en_US

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class FreezeUser {

    public User_Freeze__c uf;

    public FreezeUser(){
        uf = new User_Freeze__c();
    }

    public User_Freeze__c getUf(){
        return uf;
    }

    public PageReference save(){
        try{
            upsert uf;
        } catch(System.DmlException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }

       return null;
    }

    public PageReference salesDeskMemberReport(){
        PageReference salesDeskMemberReport = new PageReference('/');
        salesDeskMemberReport.setRedirect(true);
        return salesDeskMemberReport;
    }

}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="FreezeUser">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>

    <script src="../../soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js"
       type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">     

    function getUserInfo(){
      var userInfoById = {};

      //var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, UserId, IsFrozen, IsPasswordLocked From UserLogin WHERE UserId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('userId')");
      var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, UserId, IsFrozen, IsPasswordLocked From UserLogin order by UserId");

      var it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);

      while(it.hasNext()){
         var record = it.next();

         userInfoById[record.UserId] = record;
      }  

      var output='<table><tr><th>User</th><th>Action</th></tr>';

      var selectedUser = "'{!uf.usr__c}'";
      result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, isActive from User where Id = " + selectedUser);

      it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);

      while(it.hasNext()){
        var record = it.next();

        if (record.Id in userInfoById){
          var userInfo=userInfoById[record.Id];
          var name=record.FirstName + ' ' + record.LastName;
            output+='<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>';
          if (userInfo.IsFrozen=='true'){
            output+="<td><button onclick=\"unfreeze('" + userInfo.Id + "', '" + name + "', false);\">Unfreeze</button>";
          } else {
            output+="<button onclick=\"freeze('" + userInfo.Id + "', '" + name + "', true);\">Freeze</button>";
          }
          output+='</td></tr>';

        }
      }

      output+='</table>';

      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=output;
    }

  function freeze(id, name, freezerState){
    alert("Freezing " + name);
    var userlogin = new sforce.SObject("UserLogin");
    userlogin.Id = id;
    userlogin.IsFrozen = freezerState;
    var result = sforce.connection.update([userlogin]);

    if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
        console.log(name + " " + (freezerState?'frozen':'unfrozen'));
    } else {
        console.log("failed to freeze " + name + " " + result[0]);
    } 

    window.location.reload();
  }

  function unfreeze(id, name, freezerState){
    alert("Unfreezing " + name);
    var userlogin = new sforce.SObject("UserLogin");
    userlogin.Id = id;
    userlogin.IsFrozen = freezerState;
    var result = sforce.connection.update([userlogin]);

    if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
        console.log(name + " " + (freezerState?'unfrozen':'frozen'));
    } else {
        console.log("failed to unfreeze " + name + " " + result[0]);
    } 

    window.location.reload();
  }

  </script>

  <apex:pageMessages/>
  <apex:form> 
     <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!IF(uf.Usr__c == null, true, false)}">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select User">
            <apex:inputField value="{!uf.Usr__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" rendered="{!IF(uf.Usr__c == null, true, false)}"/>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Freeze/Unfreeze User" rendered="{!IF(uf.Usr__c != null, true, false)}">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
           <!-- <apex:outputField value="{!uf.Usr__c}"/> -->
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection>
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
              <div id="output"></div>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:commandButton action="{!salesDeskMemberReport}" value="Reassign User Sales Desks" rendered="{!IF(uf.Usr__c != null, true, false)}"/>

  </apex:form> 

  <script>
    getUserInfo();
  </script>


</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. While you can't add a custom button on the User detail, you can add a custom link through the custom links field. Which you can find in Customize --> User --> Custom Links. Then I made very minor changes to the code from Bob Buzzard's blog. What I did change around was the visualforce. Instead of having the visualforce page with a lookup field for the user you want to freeze, I made it so that when you clicked the custom link, it prepopulated that lookup field, with that user's id. I've added my solution below. Hope my struggle benefits those that run into this same issue in the future.

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class FreezeUser {

    public User u { get; set; }

    public FreezeUser(){
        u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ID = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public PageReference redirect(){
        PageReference redirectUser = new PageReference('/' + u.id);
        redirectUser.setRedirect(true);
        return redirectUser;
    }

}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="FreezeUser">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>

    <script src="../../soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js"
       type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">     

    function getUserInfo(){
      var userInfoById = {};

      var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, UserId, IsFrozen, IsPasswordLocked From UserLogin order by UserId");

      var it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);

      while(it.hasNext()){
         var record = it.next();

         userInfoById[record.UserId] = record;
      }  

      var output='<table><td><b>User<b></td><td></td><td></td><td><b>Action<b></td>';

      var selectedUser = "'{!u.id}'";
      result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, isActive from User where Id = " + selectedUser);

      it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);

      while(it.hasNext()){
        var record = it.next();

        if (record.Id in userInfoById){
          var userInfo=userInfoById[record.Id];
          var name=record.FirstName + ' ' + record.LastName;
            output+='<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>';
          if (userInfo.IsFrozen=='true'){
            output+="<td><button onclick=\"unfreeze('" + userInfo.Id + "', '" + name + "', false);\">Unfreeze</button>";
          } else {
            output+="<button onclick=\"freeze('" + userInfo.Id + "', '" + name + "', true);\">Freeze</button>";
          }
          output+='</td></tr>';

        }
      }

      output+='</table>';

      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=output;
    }

  function freeze(id, name, freezerState){
    alert("Freezing " + name);
    var userlogin = new sforce.SObject("UserLogin");
    userlogin.Id = id;
    userlogin.IsFrozen = freezerState;
    var result = sforce.connection.update([userlogin]);

    if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
        console.log(name + " " + (freezerState?'frozen':'unfrozen'));
    } else {
        console.log("failed to freeze " + name + " " + result[0]);
    } 

    window.location.reload();
  }

  function unfreeze(id, name, freezerState){
    alert("Unfreezing " + name);
    var userlogin = new sforce.SObject("UserLogin");
    userlogin.Id = id;
    userlogin.IsFrozen = freezerState;
    var result = sforce.connection.update([userlogin]);

    if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
        console.log(name + " " + (freezerState?'unfrozen':'frozen'));
    } else {
        console.log("failed to unfreeze " + name + " " + result[0]);
    } 

    window.location.reload();
  }

  </script>

  <apex:pageMessages />
  <apex:form > 

    <apex:pageBlock title="Freeze/Unfreeze User" rendered="{!IF(u.id != null, true, false)}">

        <apex:pageBlockSection >
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <div id="output"></div>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:commandButton id="back" action="{!redirect}" value="Back to User" rendered="{!IF(u.id != null, true, false)}"/>

  </apex:form> 

  <script>
    getUserInfo();
  </script>


</apex:page>
```